# Align nodes in tikz at center

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment

I have a tikz drawing that basically have "two columns of nodes". The second column is ok.
I want each column to have its nodes aligned at center (like Figure 2). But I also want the nodes of the first column to be vertically aligned with the nodes in the second column (like Figure 1).

How can I do this alignment in tikz? I tried to use matrix, but it does not seem to work with multi-line text

[image: Example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, shapes.arrows, arrows, chains, positioning, automata, backgrounds,patterns,fit,petri,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,node distance=1mm and 4cm,every edge/.style={thick,draw}, every node/.style       = {font=\small}]
  \tikzstyle{a}=[rectangle,draw=black,fill=black!5, rounded corners]
  \tikzstyle{dummy}=[circle,draw]
\node(ha1)[a] {See \textit{myers2018anomaly}};
\node(ha2)[a, below=of ha1] {See \textit{yousfi2019discovering} \textit{yousfi2019discovering}\\ \textit{yousfi2019discovering} \textit{yousfi2019discovering} \textit{yousfi2019discovering}};
\node(ha3)[a, below=of ha2] {See \textit{diamantini2017discovering}};

\node(h1)[a, left=of ha1] {Industrial control systems devices} ;
\node(h2)[a, left=of ha2] {Ubiquitous computing devices};
\node(h3)[a, left=of ha3] {Geotags};

\draw (ha1)edge(h1);
\draw (ha2)edge(h2);
\draw (ha3)edge(h3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{side-by-syde is correct, centering is wrong}

\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,node distance=1mm and 4cm,every edge/.style={thick,draw}, every node/.style       = {font=\small}]
  \tikzstyle{a}=[rectangle,draw=black,fill=black!5, rounded corners]
  \tikzstyle{dummy}=[circle,draw]
\node(ha1)[a] {See \textit{myers2018anomaly}};
\node(ha2)[a, below=of ha1] {See \textit{yousfi2019discovering} \textit{yousfi2019discovering}\\ \textit{yousfi2019discovering} \textit{yousfi2019discovering} \textit{yousfi2019discovering}};
\node(ha3)[a, below=of ha2] {See \textit{diamantini2017discovering}};

\node(h1)[a, left=of ha1] {Industrial control systems devices} ;
\node(h2)[a, below=of h1] {Ubiquitous computing devices};
\node(h3)[a, below=of h2] {Geotags};

\draw (ha1)edge(h1);
\draw (ha2)edge(h2);
\draw (ha3)edge(h3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{side-by-syde is wrong, centering is correct}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `|-` syntax on a path to place your nodes.

[image: side by side]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, shapes.arrows, arrows, chains, positioning, automata, backgrounds,patterns,fit,petri,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,node distance=1mm and 4cm,every edge/.style={thick,draw}, every node/.style       = {font=\small}]
  \tikzstyle{a}=[rectangle,draw=black,fill=black!5, rounded corners]
  \tikzstyle{dummy}=[circle,draw]
\node(ha1)[a] {See \textit{myers2018anomaly}};
\node(ha2)[a, below=of ha1] {See \textit{yousfi2019discovering} \textit{yousfi2019discovering}\\ \textit{yousfi2019discovering} \textit{yousfi2019discovering} \textit{yousfi2019discovering}};
\node(ha3)[a, below=of ha2] {See \textit{diamantini2017discovering}};

\node(h1)[a, left=of ha1] {Industrial control systems devices} ;
\path (h1) |- node(h2)[a] {Ubiquitous computing devices} (ha2) ;
\path (h2) |- node(h3)[a] {Geotags} (ha3);

\draw (ha1)edge(h1);
\draw (ha2)edge(h2);
\draw (ha3)edge(h3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{side-by-side is now right, centering is correct}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Drawing your image with use of the `tikz-cd` package is simple, arrows are straight, code is quite short:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep = 2em,
               row sep = 1ex,
               cells = {nodes={draw, semithick, rounded corners,
               fill=gray!10}
                       },
               ]

Industrial control systems devices
\ar[r]
    &   See \textit{myers2018anomaly}   \\  
Ubiquitous computing devices
\ar[r]
    &   \makecell{See 
        \textit{yousfi2019discovering yousfi2019discovering} \\  
        \textit{yousfi2019discovering yousfi2019discovering} \\ 
        \textit{yousfi2019discovering}}          \\
Geotags
\ar[r]
    &   See \textit{diamantini2017discovering}
\end{tikzcd}
\caption{side-by-side is now right, centering is correct}
\label{fig:tikzcd}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]